# Error: ')' expected compiler error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I cannot seem to figure out why i am getting this error

```
Math.java:6: error: ')' expected
        if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("+")
                                        ^
Math.java:11: error: ')' expected
                else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("x")
                                                     ^
Math.java:16: error: ')' expected
                else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("-")
                                                     ^
Math.java:21: error: ')' expected
                else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("/")
                                                     ^
4 errors
```

My code is

```
  class Math 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("+")
        {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("x")
        {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("-")
        {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("/")
        {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Something seems to be wrong, please try again.");
        }

    }
}
```

When i try to enter the closing parenthesizes where it says they should go, it get more errors. Can anyone give me a brief description of what causes this error. I am simply trying to make a program that with do math, based on arguments entered into the command line when the program is run.

For example if i entered "java Math 1 + 1" It would solve that problem and spit out "The answere is 2."

Any help you guys can offer on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a `)` on each of those lines. The fact that adding those gives *other* errors does not mean that they shouldn't be there.

Comment: you didn´t define `sum` anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `)` for each `if` condition as well as you didn't define `sum`.

```
class Math 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int sum;
        if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("+"))
        {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
        {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
        {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
        }
        else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("/"))
        {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Something seems to be wrong, please try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> you are not completing if() statement  complete if statement and use this for compare

```
if(Character.toLowerCase(arg[1])==Character.toLowerCase('+')){
}
```

or you can use switch() method

Answer (score 0):

there are two mistakes, you didn´t define sum anwhere, aswell as you are missing a paranthesis at each condition.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int sum = 0; // you had do define sum
    if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("+")) // one closing missing
    {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
    }
    else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("x")) // one closing missing
    {
    sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
    }
    else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("-")) // one closing missing
    {
    sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
    }
    else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("/")) // one closing missing
    {
    sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("Something seems to be wrong, please try again.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's go by step. The error ')' expected is why you forgot to close the '(' of if:

```
if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("+"))
```

...and so on, for each if.
plus, you didn't define **sum** anywhere, that's another error you'll encounter.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Math  { 
public static void main(String args[])
{ 
    if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("+"))
    { 
    sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
    } 
    else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
    { 
    sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
    } 
    else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
    { 
    sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
    } 
    else if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("/"))
    { 
    sum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    System.out.println("The answere is : " + sum);
    } 
    else 
    { 
    System.out.println("Something seems to be wrong, please try again.");
    } 

} }
```

This should solve your problem. You need to make sure that every bracket is closed. I think you need to use better IDE.